# Protecting a pineapple plant from snow?

Tags: fruit-trees, snow

In Jerusalem we have warm enough weather to grow pineapples, with plenty of sunshine and sunny days.

But every few years it will snow, and everything will get covered in a dusting of snow for about a day.

About once a decade we'll even get about a foot of snow and have to suffer/enjoy it for a few days.

Will our pineapple plant survive the snow, or should it be covered somehow? Any information is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Florida is probably a parallel example of climate - mostly really warm but occasionally freezing, as we know from pictures of icicles hanging from oranges. University of Florida Extension has some published materials ([see here](http://edis.ifas.ufl.edu/mg055)) - look for the section on climate.

If you are just talking about a couple of plants, then maybe a teepee formed by a couple of 4x8 sheets of plywood leaning against each other would give you a surface that would shed snow, and a blanket thrown over the ends would give additional protection. Greenhouse? I will leave you to make a business assessment on that.